# Handle currencies correctly depending on language conventions

Tags: macros, packages, languages, units

Is there a standard way of handling currencies?

Example:

- in American, you'd say "$2 a piece"
- in French, you'd say "2$ pièce"

I'd like to be able to write `\somecommand{dollars}{2}`, that would interface with `babel` or something like that so that my value is displayed correctly.

Is there an already existing package for that? (I quite often have troubles finding this kind of information about LaTeX on the web)

Comment: You can use `\iflanguage{<lang>}{<true>}{<false>}` to test if a specific language is set.

Comment: This seems as a possible (future) feature of packages like `csquotes` or `siunitx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to `grep` a language name `spanish` through a server's local `texmf` tree, and none of the matching files seem to treat currency placement. This means that no language settings for quite common Spanish language are done in any package installed at this server. I cound not choose `english` or `french` because these language names appear in different contexts than simple language specification name.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment and answer. I'll let the question open a while to see if there's something else to it and if not I'll check your answer :)